# How do I COUNT duplicates after a double GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates, distinct

I have a SQL VIEW in MSSQL that I am querying from Excel using VBA. The two columns that I am interested in are below. After I GROUP BY location code and description, there are occasions where I will get duplicate location codes and this is perfectly fine. How do I get a column that gives me a COUNT of the duplicates AFTER the GROUP BY? In the example below, the two PB-SCHOOL would have 2's in the new column and the rest would have 1's.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT LOCCODE as [Location Code], LOCATION as [Location Description]
FROM dbo.View_PendingAnalytes 
WHERE (COLDATE > DateAdd(Day, -90, GETDATE()))  
GROUP BY LOCCODE, LOCATION
```

Here's the output:

```
Location Code   |Location Description
----------------|---------------------------
LSCAKE-503      |La Salina press cake
MISSION         |Mission Linen Service
OOOCOMP         |Outfall composite
PB-SCHOOL       |123 Nowhere (BW TEST)
PB-SCHOOL       |456 Nowhere (BW TEST)
SABRA           |Sabra Dipping Co.
SLCAKE-503      |San Luis Rey centrifuge cake
SLRCLAIM        |SLR Reclaim Comp
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(*) OVER()`:

```
SELECT  LOCCODE as [Location Code], 
        LOCATION as [Location Description],
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY LOCCODE) as N
FROM dbo.View_PendingAnalytes 
WHERE (COLDATE > DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()))  
GROUP BY LOCCODE, 
         LOCATION;
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the fast solution.